# Multiple counts based on column values

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

Can some one help with some Access SQL ?

If I have the data

```
Grade of Ulcer  Source of Pressure Ulcer    
Grade 4         Admitted    
Grade 4         Admitted    
Grade 3         Admitted    
Grade 3         Admitted    
Grade 4         Admitted    
Grade 4         Admitted    
Grade 3         Acquired
```

How can I return in one query

```
                     Acquired          Admitted    
Grade 3              1                 2    
Grade 4              0                 4
```

I can do this is 2 queries but not one

Here is one example

```
SELECT 2015_pressur.[Grade of Ulcer], Count(2015_pressur.[Grade of Ulcer]) AS AcquiredCount    
FROM 2015_pressur
WHERE (((2015_pressur.[Source Of Pressure Ulcer])='Acquired'))    
GROUP BY 2015_pressur.[Grade of Ulcer];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
select
  T.[Grade of Ulcer], 
  sum(IIF(T.[Source Of Pressure Ulcer] = 'Acquired', 1, 0)) AS AcquiredCount,
  sum(IIF(T.[Source Of Pressure Ulcer] = 'Admitted', 1, 0)) AS AdmittedCount    
from 2015_pressur as T
where T.[Source Of Pressure Ulcer] in ('Acquired', 'Admitted')
group by  T.[Grade of Ulcer]
```

Comment: ah, I didn't knew `CASE WHEN` was supported in access

Comment: @ughai oops, missed access tag in question. I doubt Access supports `case when`. Will change answer to more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SWITCH` with `GROUP BY` like this.

```
SELECT
    2015_pressur.[Grade of Ulcer],
    SUM(SWITCH(2015_pressur.[Source Of Pressure Ulcer] = 'Acquired',1,true,0)) Acquired,
    SUM(SWITCH(2015_pressur.[Source Of Pressure Ulcer] = 'Admitted',1,true,0)) Admitted
FROM 2015_pressur
GROUP BY 2015_pressur.[Grade of Ulcer]
```

Comment: I couldnt get Case when to work with Access, iif works fine though
sum(iif(T.[Source Of Pressure Ulcer] = 'Acquired', 1, 0)) ... Many thanks for your help everyone can't believe how fast you guys (or gals) are.. This has really helped me out ! Thanks again